# How do I make doxygen skip all (sub)-namespaces named "detail"?

Tags: c++, documentation, doxygen

I'm using [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org/) to generate documentation for my C++ project.

I generally want doxygen not not skip anything defined in my files; but an exception to this rule is whenever I "hide" something by placing it in a namespace, or a sub-namespace, named `detail` (this is pretty common practice in many libraries).

So how can I get doxygen to skip all namespaces `foo::bar::baz::etc::leaf_namespace` such that one of the elements is `detail`? And not list anything under that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, as Jakub notes, `EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS` is the option to use. In my specific case, the exact configuration setting is:

```
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS        = detail::*,*::detail::*
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_exclude_symbols) config option.