# how can i hide certain parts of a function signature from doxygen?

Tags: c++, documentation, doxygen, documentation-generation

I have some C++ code like:

```cpp
template <class T>
auto frobozzle(T t) -> typename detail::ugly_metafunction<T>::type;
```

I would like it to appear in my (Doxygen-generated) documentation like this:

```
template <class T>
auto frobozzle(T t) -> unspecified;
```

... but ideally also syntax highlighted. I can't figure how to substitute the return type with an italicized *`unspecified`*. Is it possible?

Comment: I have no idea (C++20 concepts would clean things up quite a bit), but in C++17 I usually cleanup the trailing expressions with helpers which make the "ugly" thing less ugly. e.g `template<typename T> using frobozzle_return_t = typename detail::ugly_metafunction<T>::type;` and then `template <typename T> auto frobozzle(T t) -> frobozzle_return_t<T>`. This works for cleaning up long std::enable_if_t expressions too

Comment: Then how do you clean up the definition of the `frobozzle_return_t` alias template?

Comment: Put the aliases in a namespace and exclude that namespace. Eg. a `traits` namespace or something. I think this post [how do I make doxygen exclude a namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43437720/how-do-i-make-doxygen-skip-all-sub-namespaces-named-detail) covers that. Note I am just mostly brainstorming, not tested this myself. :)

Comment: What I meant is that I do this kind of "cleanup" regardless of doxygen. And I did not test it for doxygen specifically

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? What do you mean with "I would like it to appear in my (Doxygen-generated) documentation like this:", where would you like to see this, should `unspecified` be present or ... ?